# Java How to read a file line by line. Each line is mixed with both ascII and binary

Tags: java, io, binary, inputstream, bufferedreader

I have a file have multiple lines.

For each line the format is

```
"String A" "String B" "binary data"
```

What I want to do is adding "String C" in front of each line

```
"String C" "String A" "String B" "binary data"
```

Now I am using BufferedReader.readline(), it seems like this method has problem when reading binary data.

Can any one give me some suggestions on solving this question?

Comment: Can the "binary data" contain embedded newlines?

Comment: As @aix points out, if you are using binary data you can't determine that it's separated in lines, unless you have a way to know how long it is, and it still would be problematic. It would be far better to encode the binary data in base64 encoding or something like it, so it doesn't clash with the other text.

Comment: What do you mean by binary data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have binary data in your file you shouldn't use the readLine() method which assumes that your line will end with '\r','\n' or "\r\n". The "binary data" can contain that sequence by chance and mess up your readLine().

Generally speaking, you shouldn't mix binary data with text data.

Answer (score 2):

I think You have to read binary buffers and interpret your format yourself, i.e. find the position of text extract bytes and transform them to String.

Readers can not read binary data. No way.

Answer (score 2):

A much more serious problem than "binary data may contain newlines" is obviously that binary data may not even contain valid unicode codepoints at all! Hence under no circumstances should you ever interpret binary data as text, but the other way is just fine.

Which means: Read the data into a bytebuffer and interpret it yourself.